# JQUERY - Changing Div Dimension , from top left/right or bottom left/right

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, height, width

i'm writing my personal website , and i have 4 divs contained in a container div (see the image)

[image: As you can see , the dashed one is the container div]

Now on click I wanted to resize the clicked div to the container's div dimension

I did it.

Now my question is there is a way to resize:

- the second one to top-right to bottom left
- the 3rd one to bottom left to top right
- the 4th one from bottom-right to top-left

**HTML**

http://pastebin.com/mid0ssC6

**CSS**

http://pastebin.com/sx4BL9Jv

**JQUERY**

http://pastebin.com/1yG3vkew

---

---

I Found a Solution , I will post it soon :)

Comment: In case it helps, here is a jsBin of the puzzle as described by the OA: http://jsbin.com/sinug/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: @Kolban I didn't thought about jsBin , thanks for your contribution :D

Comment: In your logic you have if state==1 ... state = 0 - (1+state).  Perhaps use a boolean instead.  if state == true ... state = !state.  This isn't any answer to your puzzle just a comment on the code while I was looking at it.

Comment: @Kolban I used this expression instead of writing 

If (state==1) then state = 0 ;
else then state = 1 ;

Comment: Updated the jsBin with a missing variable initialization: http://jsbin.com/sinug/3/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To perform the levels of animation you are looking for will take some change in thinking.  Currently, you have your images laid out as 4 `<div>` elements following each other and wrap because the width of their container would cause such.  You would instead need to position then using CSS positioning at the four corners.  See [relative positioning](http://learnlayout.com/position.html).

Now, in order to animate the item you wish you would need to know its final desired size and its final desired endpoint position.  You would then animate from the starting size and position to those final values over the desired duration.  The resizing will make it the final desired size but you will also have to move the position of the image at the same rate as the resize scale.  For example, when the new icon is 50% larger, its position should be 50% of the way from the start to the end.  If we consider that the upper/left of the image is where the image is anchored then it has to move in each "tick" in such a way that the fixed corner of your moving image stays in exactly the same place.

I realize that this isn't a coded solution for you but the nature of Stack Exchange is more "answering questions" than it is "code me a solution".

Comment: Yes , this is the concept basically , but i was asking if there is a jquery option/function that could help me instead of writing the code .

If there isn't a cooked solution ,
I think that I should moving the image trying to keep anchored to its own corner , so :

- 1% resize 
- positioning 

reapeted until div size is 100%

Comment: @MartinMcFlyDeLuca  Unfortunately I don't know of such a baked out solution or template.  That doesn't mean that one doesn't exist, merely that I don't know where to find one.  Sorry my friend.

Comment: As always I have to slog xD

Answer (score 0):

This is incomplete answer ther is another problem but logically the solution of the problem is the follow :

http://pastebin.com/izrfcJDq

Obviously , divs position has to be changed to relative.

The problem is that the while cycle has to be timed .

The native javascript method SetInterval() is not good for this purpose because it still continue going after the cycle is ended .