# Change timing of a cycle without setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, cycle, timing

I'm Trying to solve this problem :

[JQUERY - Changing Div Dimension , from top left/right or bottom left/right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26792488/jquery-changing-div-dimension-from-top-left-right-or-bottom-left-right?noredirect=1#comment42182052_26792488)

by creating my own resizing animation function .

I tried recursive solution but the problem still remains , it does it instantly , and I can't see no animation at all

```
function RelativeCornerResizer(Elements , StartSize , EndSize , Unit , Left , Top)
{   
    //var I = StartSize ;
    var SSpx = "" , LeftPx="" , TopPx="";

    LeftPx = (Left)+Unit; 
    TopPx = (Top)+Unit;


    if(StartSize < EndSize)
    {       
            StartSize+=2;

            SSpx = StartSize+Unit;

            if(Left!=0) LeftPx = (Left-StartSize)+Unit;
            if(Top!=0)  TopPx = (Top-StartSize)+Unit;

            $(Elements).css({'width': SSpx,'height': SSpx});
            $(Elements).css({'left' : LeftPx , 'top' : TopPx});

            setTimeout(RelativeCornerResizer(Elements , StartSize , EndSize , Unit , Left , Top),50);
    }

}
```

Comment: Where is your `setTimeout()`?  All I see is a blocking loop that freezes the program until the entire div is resized...

Comment: setTimeout() only repeat it once , i need the while to be repeated until the div is resized , but each cycle has to slow down

Comment: _“I can't use `setInterval()` because the function continue to be executed after an interval”_ – that’s why `clearInterval` exists …

Comment: @CBroe I know this , but I need it to be executed only when the animation is ended , I know that it's complete when startsize reach endsize , clearinterval needs setinterval id , but i need to "feed" clearinterval with setinterval id , only when animation is ended ... i don't know how to explain the problem , i already tried with clearinterval

Comment: Any reason why you are trying to “program” the whole animation in JS yourself here – instead of just using CSS Transitions or Animations …?

Comment: @CBroe Because in jquery exists only resizing from topleft corner , but i have 4 divs positioned in a certain way , here is explained better

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26792488/jquery-changing-div-dimension-from-top-left-right-or-bottom-left-right?noredirect=1#comment42182052_26792488

Comment: _“Because in jquery […]”_ – that was not the question; the question was why use JS for the animation in the first place? If you don’t know what CSS Transitions and CSS Animations are capable of, you should go read up on them …

Comment: @CBroe , could you send me a good link about ?

Comment: Google exists, use it :p

Comment: Ok thank you :D I'll do my homeworks :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setTimeout(RelativeCornerResizer(Elements , …),50);
```

This does not do what you expect it to do.

`setTimeout` expects either a string, or a function *reference* as first parameter.

But you are not passing a reference here, you are *calling* the function `RelativeCornerResizer`, so that it gets executed *immediately*, and only its return value (which is nothing) gets passed to `setTimeout` … and therefor everything is happening “at once”.

You can use an anonymous function to bypass this problem:

```
setTimeout(
  function() {
    RelativeCornerResizer(Elements, …);
  },
  50
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setTimeout` inside another timeout function to continue the loop. Take for example:

```
function timeoutLoopFunction() {
  ... do animation stuff here for one frame ...

  // Now queue up the same update again for another
  // update if the animation is not finished yet
  if (shouldHaveAnotherFrame) {
    // Change the hardcoded 50 to a variable one that changes
    // over time if necessary.
    setTimeout(timeoutLoopFunction, 50);
  }
}

// Start the animation by calling the function.
timeoutLoopFunction();
```

Comment: I'll try this solution and let you know :D thank you